# Coreldraw Suite #7 - Colour Graphics

Tags: corel-draw

I am using Coreldraw Suite # 7 and it's not printing my graphics in colour can anyone please advise what setting I need to adjust to change to colour?  It is displayed as colour on screen but not in print preview.  Thank you Pip

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your printer's default preferences? When you open the "Print" dialog box, click on "Print Preview" at the bottom left. This should show you rough estimation of what your print output will be. I mention this so that you don't end up printing a bunch of documents, wasting your expensive ink/toner.

If it's greyscale, then it's definitely a printer setting. Now, it's difficult to judge because each printer will generally have its own driver installed, so the screen you see when you go to your printing preferences will be different to what I see. But in there you will have to define the output as either colour or greyscale/black & white.